# Turning a loop into a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

I am writing this code that takes all pixels of an image and then stores them into a list.

My objective is transform this loop into a list comprehension.

```
# Take the image
im = Image.open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/IMG_170619_114715_0007_NIR.tif")
#load it
pixels = im.load() 
# take the width and the height
width, height = im.size
```

Then comes the loop...

```
all_pixels = []
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        cpixel = pixels[x,y]
        all_pixels.append(cpixel)
```

My first attempt was this...

```
all_pixels=[[pixels[x,y] for y in range(height)] for x in range(width)]
```

And it is working, but when I do **len(all_pixels)** to see if I am having all the pixels I have only 1280 values which means that the calculations are not correctly done in the lsit comprehension...

`len(all_pixels)
Out[143]: 1280`

We should have something like..

`len(all_pixels)
Out[105]: 1228800`

Any help please ? Why is the list comprehension not calculating the same thing as the loop ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested for should come after the parent one:

```
all_pixels = [pixels[x,y] for x in range(width) for y in range(height)]
```

BTW, you don't need the indexing, you can simply use the nested comprehension to flatten you image:

```
all_pixels = [x for row in pixels for x in row]
```

The image is a numpy array, `flatten` is another way to achieve your result.

```
all_pixels = pixels.flatten().to_list()
```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think that makes any difference.

Comment: And a question BTW, is this making my code (calculations) faster ?? To replace loops with list comprehension ?

Comment: @MouradOverFlow Yes, list comprehensions are faster than vanilla for loops.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye of course, what should I do ? I don't have 15 reputation so I couldn't vote for your answer.

Comment: @MouradOverFlow You don't need rep to accept an answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)